# Unable to doubleclick in selenium webdriver c# 1

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, double-click

I am getting an error message

> 'driver' is a 'variable' but is used like a method

whenever I am creating an action class instance.

```
InternetExplorerDriver ie = new InternetExplorerDriver(path);
Action action = new Action(ie);
```

Comment: You can call the driver like `ie()` ??

Comment: doing that is giving the same error.

Comment: Logicaly because a `System.Action` just recieve methods, and if you can't call `ie()` you can't create the `System.Action` with the `ie` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `Actions` from `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions`, not `Action` from `System`, which expect a method as you can see in the error message

```
Actions actions = new Actions(ie);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.